# how to get rows by fives by groups in mysql

Tags: mysql

I hava a table which have columns like id, mac,rssi,mac and time .I want to select rssi according to grouping by mac by fives. but I couldn't.

How can I get five rssi rows according to distinct mac rows

my table is

```
id  okuyucu     mac rssi    batarya zaman
1   AC:Co   device 1    -64 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.096
2   AC:Co   device 2    -72 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.184
3   AC:Co   device 1    -76 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.305
4   AC:Co   device 1    -82 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.493
5   AC:Co   device 2    -73 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.946
6   AC:Co   device 3    -71 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.106
7   AC:Co   device 1    -67 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.210
8   AC:Co   device 4    -87 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.512
9   AC:Co   device 2    -72 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.525
10  AC:Co   device 1    -64 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.621
11  AC:Co   device 3    -70 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.921
12  AC:Co   device 2    -86 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.321
13  AC:Co   device 2    -73 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.585
14  AC:Co   device 1    -66 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.641
15  AC:Co   device 3    -67 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.838
16  AC:Co   device 1    -69 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.956
17  AC:Co   device 2    -73 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.406
18  AC:Co   device 4    -74 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.665
19  AC:Co   device 1    -64 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.678
20  AC:Co   device 3    -66 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.765
21  AC:Co   device 3    -71 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.970
22  AC:Co   device 1    -65 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:20.278
23  AC:Co   device 3    -70 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:20.647
```

in this table I want to list 5 rssi values of every device How can I do this?
my desired output is

```
9   AC:Co   device 2    -72 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:17.525
17  AC:Co   device 2    -73 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.406
5   AC:Co   device 2    -73 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.946
12  AC:Co   device 2    -86 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.321
13  AC:Co   device 2    -73 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:18.585




19  AC:Co   device 1    -64 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:19.678
22  AC:Co   device 1    -65 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:20.278
3   AC:Co   device 1    -76 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.305
4   AC:Co   device 1    -82 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.493
1   AC:Co   device 1    -64 NULL    2020-08-31 13:17:16.096
```

like this

mysql version is 8.x

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Show desired output. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: *I want to list 5 rssi values of every device* 5 random values? 5 definite values? if last - how to determine what values must be selected?

Comment: I have edited....

Comment: Again - how to determine what 5 values from all possible must be returned? For example for device 2 - why shown rows are returned and why exactly row 2 is ignored?

Comment: last 5 rows according to id

Comment: *last 5 rows according to id* For device 1 the row id=1 is NOT in last five with guarantee...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mac ORDER BY ???) rn
              FROM source_table )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 6
```

You **must** specify any definite rows ordering (which must provide rows uniqueness !!! if not then the output will be non-deterministic).

---

> last 5 rows according to id

`ORDER BY id DESC`